# How to optimize checking elements in a vector in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

```
vector<unsigned> listNumbers; //listNumbers vector contains about 1000 million elements
vector<unsigned> storageVec; 
for(vector<unsigned>::iterator it=listNumbers.begin(), l=listNumbers.end(); it!=l; ++it)
{
            if(check_if_condition_satisfied(*it))
                   storageVec.push_back(*it);
}
```

vector "listNumbers" contains about a 1000 million element and I need to check whether the elements in "listNumbers" satisfies a certain condition using check_if_condition_satisfied. Unfortunately, checking check_if_condition_satisfied element at a time is very time consuming. Is there some way by which I may parallelize the check in C++11

Comment: Do you need cross platform solution?

Comment: [`std::all_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) with a proper execution policy. But it's c++17 unfortunately.

Comment: Sounds like what you really want to do is not check each one, but store it in a way that means you can cut the set down faster

Comment: please provide a more realistic example, you need to store the results of the check? or do you need to check if all satisfy the condition?

Comment: Are you using the result of `check_if_contidion_satisfied`? Is it thread-safe? This example makes no sense.

Comment: Threads perhaps? But paralellizing the search will only help so much, you might want to consider redesigning with other data structures that fit your use-case better.

Comment: openmp parallel for maybe fit your requirement, however it depend on the compiler.

Comment: Just to be sure: Checking 1E9 items will take a long time no matter what. Just *iterating* them will take siginificant time.

Comment: Is it a read only vector ? If yes, then I would first attempt how `sort + binary_search` would fare against any threaded version.

Comment: Just a quick point, you've got a vector, of unsigned values, with 1000 million entries?  How many of them can be expected to be duplicates?

Comment: How do you get this list of numbers? maybe, instead o searching for elements use two vectors, when appending new element append it to the right vector and then no search is needed

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`std::future`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future) and [`std::async`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) to easily parallelize the computation.

Untested *(pseudo)* code:

```
// You need to keep track of all futures you spawn. 
std::vector<std::future<bool>> futs;

// Spawn a future for every "block" that you want to check.    
futs.emplace_back(std::async(std::launch::async, 
    [&]{ return check_condition_range(listNumbers, 0, 10000); }));

futs.emplace_back(std::async(std::launch::async, 
    [&]{ return check_condition_range(listNumbers, 10000, 20000); }));

// (Ideally you would divide your range evenly depending on the number of threads you
// can spawn, and generate the futures in a loop.)

// ...

// "Accumulate" the results of every future.
// This blocks until all futures are done.
bool satisfied = true;
for(auto& f : futs)
{
    if(!f.get()) 
    {
        satisfied = false;
    }
}
```

[Here's a **simple example on wandbox**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/9f7uThqRvBNoinZr).

---

If you had access to C++17, you could simply use:

```
std::all_of(std::execution::par, 
    std::begin(listNumbers), std::end(listNumbers),         
    check_if_condition_satisfied);
```

---

> Sorry I also need to store the results in a common vector.

Simply change your future type to `std::future<decltype(listNumbers)::iterator>`, so that every future will return an iterator instead of a bool.

Afterwards, you can do something similar to this:

```
std::vector<decltype(listNumbers)::iterator> result;
for(auto& f : futs) result.emplace_back(f.get());
// use `result`
```

Comment: Even after increasing the range there might still be thousands of threads. Not really something a normal workstation can handle.

Comment: 1.  You'd probably want to spawn the future in a loop, rather than writing it out long-hand.

Comment: @MartinBonner: definitely. I was just trying to illustrate the idea of separating the range in small blocks. I'll improve the answer.

Comment: 2.  If the check is CPU bound (rather than going to be waiting on IO), you really want exactly one thread per core (and no more).

Comment: 3.  If the check is IO bound, then I suspect the answer involves some sort of asynchronous IO

Comment: Just to be sure I haven't missed something: the `&&=` operator doesn't exist (yet?), does it?

Comment: @Quentin: not yet, fixed :)

Comment: Sorry I also need to store the results in a common vector.

Answer (score 2):

You can be precise in controlling exactly how many threads you create to compute your task in parallel. Here is a solution that does this explicitly, and assigns consecutive areas of the input vector for each thread to seek saving the results into a binary vector. The main thread itself also participates in the workload. At the end all passed results are copied into the storage vector in a separate single pass (to avoid contention overhead of concurrently writing into it straight from the checking threads).

Live code [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b112b74b01a38538).

```
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>

bool check_if_condition(int a)
{
    return true;
}

void doWork(std::vector<int>& input, std::vector<bool>& results, size_t current, size_t end, std::atomic_int& totalPassed)
{
    end = std::min(end, input.size());
    int numPassed = 0;
    for(; current < end; ++current) {
        if(check_if_condition(input[current])) {
            results[current] = true;
            ++numPassed;
        }
    }

    totalPassed.fetch_add(numPassed);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> input(1000000);
    std::vector<bool> results(input.size());
    std::atomic_int numPassed(0);

    auto numThreads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();

    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    auto blockSize = input.size() / numThreads;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < numThreads - 1; ++i) {
        threads.emplace_back(doWork, std::ref(input), std::ref(results), i * blockSize, (i+1) * blockSize, std::ref(numPassed));
    }

    //also do work in this thread
    doWork(input, results, (numThreads-1) * blockSize, numThreads*blockSize, numPassed);

    for(auto& thread : threads)
        thread.join();

    std::vector<int> storage;
    storage.reserve(numPassed.load());

    auto itRes = results.begin();
    auto itInput = input.begin();
    auto endRes = results.end();
    for(; itRes != endRes; ++itRes, ++itInput) {
        if(*itRes)
            storage.emplace_back(*itInput);
    }

    std::cout << "Done" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Your code works well but not when the size of "input" is variable. IS it possible to adjust the code to accomodate variable size input variables

Comment: What do you mean? Apart from the line declaring `input` (which obviously you can change arbitrarily or change into a parameter instead), there is nothing in the above that assumes that input is 1000000 elements. It would work with any size